# cURL GET returns unexpected result

Tags: curl

I'm sending a curl to a bot in one of the major cell carriers labs and when I do I get an unexpected result back:

```
λ curl --digest \
>     -v \
>     -X GET \
>     -d @- \
>     http://b-wit-a2pgw-4444.company.sncrmmp.com/up22/rcs/chatbots?ho=404045&client_vendor=COMPANY&client_version=ANDR5.2
[1] 2047
[2] 2048
[2]+  Done                    client_vendor=COMPANY
```

These are the instructions I have for doing the curl:

```
Execute the following request:
•   GET [BOTSGW_SERVICE_HOST]/up22/rcs/chatbots?ho=404045&client_vendor=WITS&client_version=ANDR5.2
•   With Digest Auth
```

This is the response I am supposed to get back:

```
200 Ok
{
    "bots": [
        {
            "id": "sip:GSMA@bots.wcs-dev.company.com",
            "name": "GSMA Test Bot",
            "verified": false,
            "nickname": "@GSMA",
            "featured": false,
            "subscribed": true,
            "allowSubscribers": true,
            "allowOperatorMessaging": false,
            "new": false
        },
(...)
   ],
    "itemsReturned": 10,
    "startIndex": 0,
    "totalItems": 12
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should put your URL into quotes `&` and `=` because these are reserved operators in bash and they should be escaped

```
curl --digest \
 -v \
 -X GET \
 -d @- \
 'http://b-wit-a2pgw-4444.company.sncrmmp.com/up22/rcs/chatbotsho=404045&client_vendor=WITS&client_version=ANDR5.2'
```

or

```
curl --digest \
 -v \
 -X GET \
 -d @- \
 http://b-wit-a2pgw-4444.company.sncrmmp.com/up22/rcs/chatbotsho\=404045\&client_vendor\=WITS\&client_version\=ANDR5.2
```